# Python. Telebot. Как заставить telegram-bot принимать ответ второй раз подряд

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бот по бросанию кубиков и магическому шару в одном.
Создал кнопки: бросать кубик или магический шар. Нажав на "бросать кубик" - можно выбрать количество граней.

**Проблема:** Бот не реагирует на второй ввод текста с клавиатуры или через кнопку. Ошибок не выдает. Не могу разобраться как заставить его принимать ввод с клавиатуры дважды подряд.

**Часть написанного кода:**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(massage):
    bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, '<b>Hello my hero, would you like to know your destiny?</b>', parse_mode='html')
    photo = open('gendalf.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(massage.chat.id, photo)

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

    dnd_dice = types.KeyboardButton('DnD dices')
    magic_ball = types.KeyboardButton('Magic ball')

    markup.add(dnd_dice, magic_ball)

    bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, 'Press the button', reply_markup=markup)




@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(antwort):

    if antwort.text == 'DnD dices':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

        d4 = types.KeyboardButton('D4')
        d6 = types.KeyboardButton('D6')
        d8 = types.KeyboardButton('D8')
        d10 = types.KeyboardButton('D10')
        d12 = types.KeyboardButton('D12')
        d20 = types.KeyboardButton('D20')
        d100 = types.KeyboardButton('D100')

        markup.add(d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, d20, d100)

        bot.send_message(antwort.chat.id, 'Choose the dice you need or press the button', reply_markup=markup)

        @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
        def try_dice(result):
            try:
                number = int(result.text[1:])
                answer = random.randint(1, number)
                bot.send_message(result.chat.id, f' You have: ☻ <b>{answer}</b> ☻', parse_mode='html')
                bot.send_message(result.chat.id, 'Do you want to go on? Just write a number or press the button')
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    number = int(result.text[0:])
                    answer = random.randint(1, number)
                    bot.send_message(result.chat.id, f' You have: ☻ <b>{answer}</b> ☻', parse_mode='html')
                    bot.send_message(result.chat.id, 'Do you want to go on? Just write a number or press the button')
                except ValueError:
                    bot.send_message(result.chat.id, "<b>I don't understand you.</b>", parse_mode='html')
```

[image: Скриншот реакции бота]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не проверял, но вроде норм.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
# делайте аннотации, если вы работаете в IDE
# да и вообще это облегчит понимание кода
def start(massage: types.Message):
    # вместо двух отправок, я бы добавил caption к send_photo
    # bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, '<b>Hello my hero, would you like to know your destiny?</b>', parse_mode='html')
    # photo = open('gendalf.jpg', 'rb')
    # bot.send_photo(massage.chat.id, photo)
    # а еще лучше юзать этот класс для файлов/фото и тд
    photo = InputFile('gendalf.jpg')
    bot.send_photo(massage.chat.id, photo)

    # какой смысл создавать кучу переменных? Да и вообще
    # для реплай клавиатуры достаточно строк
    # markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    # dnd_dice = types.KeyboardButton('DnD dices')
    # magic_ball = types.KeyboardButton('Magic ball')
    # markup.add(dnd_dice, magic_ball)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add('DnD dices', 'Magic ball')

    bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, 'Press the button', reply_markup=markup)


# не рекомендую подобный фильтр, научитесь разбивать по хендлерам ваши кнопки
# ну кроме тех которые одинаково/почти одинаково обрабатываются
# короче вместо
# @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
# делай
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == "DnD dices")
# что за antwort? У вас же четкий обьект месседж
# def handle_DnD_dices(antwort: types.Message):
def handle_DnD_dices(message: types.Message):
    # больше не нужное
    # if antwort.text == 'DnD dices':
    # аналогично тому что я писал выше
    # markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    #
    # d4 = types.KeyboardButton('D4')
    # d6 = types.KeyboardButton('D6')
    # d8 = types.KeyboardButton('D8')
    # d10 = types.KeyboardButton('D10')
    # d12 = types.KeyboardButton('D12')
    # d20 = types.KeyboardButton('D20')
    # d100 = types.KeyboardButton('D100')
    #
    # markup.add(d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, d20, d100)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add('D4', 'D6' 'D8' 'D10', 'D12', 'D20', 'D100')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose the dice you need or press the button', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, try_dice)


# НИКОГДА НЕ ЗАПИХИВАЙТЕ ХЕНДЛЕР ВНУТРЬ ДРУГОГО ХЕНДЛЕРА!!
# а вообще на не нужен даже декоратор. Мы уже записали его в register_next_step_handler выше
# @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
# и что опять за result?! Это обьект Message!
def try_dice(message: types.Message):
    # логика этого кода, чертовски странная
    # try:
    #     number = int(message.text[1:])
    #     answer = random.randint(1, number)
    #     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' You have: ☻ <b>{answer}</b> ☻', parse_mode='html')
    #     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Do you want to go on? Just write a number or press the button')
    # except ValueError:
    #     try:
    #         number = int(message.text[0:])
    #         answer = random.randint(1, number)
    #         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' You have: ☻ <b>{answer}</b> ☻', parse_mode='html')
    #         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Do you want to go on? Just write a number or press the button')
    #     except ValueError:
    #         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>I don't understand you.</b>", parse_mode='html')
    ### я бы сделал так
    str_number = message.text[1:]
    # проверяем число ли то что написал юзер
    if str_number.isdigit():
        number = int(str_number)
        answer = random.randint(1, number)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         text=f'You have: ☻ <b>{answer}</b> ☻'
                              f'Do you want to go on? Just write a number or press the button',
                         parse_mode='html')
    # если нет, требуем жать на кнопку
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose the dice you need or press the button')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, try_dice)
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе. Мне ещё много предстоит научиться